# When will three cycles line up?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Three seniors $x,y$ and $z$ live in a complex and love eating pizza. $X$ eats pizza every $5$ days, $y$ every $7$ days, and $z$ every $11$ days. $X$ & $Z$ had pizza together yesterday and $Y$ had pizza today. When will they have pizza together?
>
> Use a linear diophantine equation or chinese remainder theorem to solve.

I think the solution is $55$ days because $55$ is divisible by $5$ & $11$ and $56$ (the next day) is divisible by $7$ but i'm not sure how to create an equation to satisfy this problem. Can someone help me set up an equation?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Find integral solution to $55x = 1 + 7y$.

Comment: how did you come up with the equation? Isn't 55 the solution so why is the solution needed to set up the diophantine equation?

Comment: $55x$ days from yesterday should coincide with $7y$ days from today, hence the equation.

Comment: ok, so now i am using the euclidean algorithm to find a solution to the linear diophantine equation. I got the gcd of 55 and 7 to be one and found one solution, 1=7(8)-55(1) the problem is my original equation is 55x-7y=1